# Referencing assembly versions in VSIX with multiple VS versions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vsix

I have a Visual Studio extension (VSIX) that is meant to work in both VS2015 and VS2017. The VSIX relies on `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Framework`, and since I'm developing on VS2017 I have the following line in my csproj:

```
<Reference 
    Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Framework, Version=15.0.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" 
/>
```

However, when users try to install my extension in VS2015, they understandably get an exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Framework, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.

How am I supposed to reference `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Framework` in a VSIX that targets both VS versions? If I switch the version from 15 to 14, I can no longer build on my machine since VS2015 isn't installed (and I also suspect there will be issues for users installing in VS2017).

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. Either build against the lowest supported version and trust the bindingRedirects in the devenv.exe.config load the right versions or build a separate vsix for each version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you mean that VS2017 comes with redirects in devenv.exe.config to make it automatically load previous versions of standard DLLs? If so that's a pretty satisfactory solution...

Comment: Yes it does. Though not all assemblies *are* backwards compatible. So this needs extensive testing.

Comment: Thanks, if you put that in an answer I'll flag it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The devenv.exe.config file of VS 2017 in folder Common7\IDE has this binding redirect for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Framework from version 14.0.0.0 to 15.0.0.0:

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Framework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="8.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

So your project needs to reference version 14.0.0.0. From where? Two approaches:

1. Use a [NuGet package to get Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Framework/). (ensure to reference version 14.0.x, not version 15.x)
2. Create a folder, put inside Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Framework version 14.0.x and add the folder to source control along with your project.

Comment: I don't get it. He should have used 14.0.0.0 for VS 2015 and 15.0.0.0 for VS 2017. Won't the VSIX project always use 15.0.0.0 because of bindingRedirect?

Comment: A VSIX is a deployment mechanism for a package Dll. The package Dll project must reference version 14.0.0.0 to work with VS 2015 and VS 2017. The VSIX will deploy the package independently to VS 2015 and VS 2017. VS 2015 will use 14.0.0.0. VS 2017 will redirect 14.0.0.0 to 15.0.0.0